# how to add api gateway ( with api key) to an exiting lambda cloudformation template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I am learning SAM Cli and working with a existing template for a lambda function. I'm not 100% sure , if an API gateway is already created with this. but if not i want to extend this by adding an api gateway, with possibly authetication mechanism with an api key. also , I have created VPC with private/public subnets. how/where can i define those in this template. any code samples would be helpful.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: Sample SAM Template 

Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 3

Resources:
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: hello_world/
      Handler: app.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.8
      Events:
        HelloWorld:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source:
          Properties:
            Path: /hello
            Method: get

Outputs:
 
  HelloWorldApi:
    Description: "API Gateway endpoint URL for Prod stage for Hello World function"
    Value: !Sub "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/hello/"
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Description: "Hello World Lambda Function ARN"
    Value: !GetAtt HelloWorldFunction.Arn
  HelloWorldFunctionIamRole:
    Description: "Implicit IAM Role created for Hello World function"
    Value: !GetAtt HelloWorldFunctionRole.Arn
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't provided any template code regarding the API geteway. Thus in general, if you want to use **API key**, you have to use **three components** in your template:

- [AWS::ApiGateway::UsagePlan](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-usageplan.html) to create a **usage plan** for the api,
- [AWS::ApiGateway::ApiKey](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-apikey.html) to create **API key**
- [AWS::ApiGateway::UsagePlanKey](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-usageplankey.html) to **associate** the key with the plan.

Comment: thanks for your comment. I need help with the API gateway template code. I have been learning different components but not sure how to link API gateway code and the lambda code. a sample api gateway and how it can be linked to lambda would greatly help for me to move forward with the api key and other set up.

Comment: @ozil My suggestion would be to attempt on writing the template file, and make new question with some actually code example and error messages of why it does not work.

Comment: I will try that. one question , once we set the ApiKey resource in the cloudformation template. How is the acutal api key generated?

Comment: @ozil I think is random.

Comment: I open a new question for this. take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63460699/how-to-wire-up-lambda-and-api-gateway-in-cloud-formation-template