# how to wire up lambda and api gateway in cloud formation template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am learning working with AWS lambda and api gateway. I started with sam cli, initialized a hello world template ( code below). when deploy.yaml file is generated via - sam package ... command and stack is generated via cloud formation , it looks like this already generates an api end point. I wanted to create an api gateway with resource, methods, usage plan , api key and so forth. so I started adding following resources to the original template. How can i wire up my api gateway with the lambda function.

```
ApiGatewayRestApi:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi
    Properties:
      ApiKeySourceType: HEADER
      Description: An API Gateway with a Lambda Integration
      EndpointConfiguration:
        Types:
          - EDGE
      Name: lambda-api

  ApiGatewayResource:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Resource
    Properties:
      ParentId: !GetAtt ApiGatewayRestApi.RootResourceId
      PathPart: 'lambda'
      RestApiId: !Ref ApiGatewayRestApi

  ApiGatewayMethod:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Method
    Properties:
      ApiKeyRequired: false
      AuthorizationType: NONE
      HttpMethod: GET
      ResourceId: !Ref ApiGatewayResource
      RestApiId: !Ref ApiGatewayRestApi
```

original template

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  simple-node-api
  Sample SAM Template for simple-node-api

Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 3

Resources:
  HelloWorldfunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: hello-world/
      Handler: app.lambdaHandler
      Runtime: python3.7
      Events:
        HelloWorld:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /{proxy+}
            Method: get

Outputs:
  HelloWorldApi:
    Description: API Gateway endpoint URL for Prod stage for Hello World function
    Value:
      Fn::Sub: https://${ServerlessHttpApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/hello/"
  HelloWorldfunction:
    Description: Express Backend Lambda Function ARN
    Value: !Sub HelloWorldfunction.Arn
  HelloWorldFunctionIamRole:
    Description: Implicit IAM Role created for Hello World function
    Value: !Sub HelloWorldFunctionRole.Arn
```

Comment: aren't you already doing that? your serverless function block is your lambda function. you will use the `CodeUri ` attribute to point the source code of your lambda function. the URI could be the s3 location of a zip file with the code.

Comment: @ArunK - thanks. I am not 100% clear on how exactly that works. can you point me to a example.

Comment: This is a pretty good example imo: https://bl.ocks.org/magnetikonline/c314952045eee8e8375b82bc7ec68e88